# Safari Not Updating UI During Form Submission

Tags: javascript, forms, safari, prototypejs

I've got a JavaScript function that submits a form.

The first step of my function is to disable it (to prevent multiple clicks) and apply a class that better illustrates that it's disabled. I also change the text to 'Please Wait...'

The next step is to validate my form. If validation fails, revert the changes in the first step, to return the button to its normal state.

If validation passes, submit the form.

This all essentially happens in the same process.

What I find is happening, is that in Safari, the first stage of the process (the button styles) is all but ignored. Upon further digging, I realised that it **is** working but the UI isn't redrawing until after the process completes. The problem here is that the completion of the process is a redirect away from the page, so the user never gets to see 'Please wait...'

Then I explored why Safari isn't redrawing the UI and I discovered a number of fixes for this, one such example is below:

```
// Aims to trigger the redraw by 'resetting' it
elem.style.display='none';
elem.offsetHeight;
elem.style.display='';
```

Another one I tried was deliberately hiding and showing the element before/after the update utilising Prototype (which is the primary JavaScript library on the system):

```
elem.hide();
elem.addClassName('disabledBtn');
elem.disable();
elem.update('Please Wait');
elem.show();
```

Another was to create a 'redraw' method to force a redraw.

```
Element.addMethods({
    redraw: function(element){
        element = $(element);
        var n = document.createTextNode(' ');
        element.appendChild(n);
        (function(){n.parentNode.removeChild(n)}).defer();
        return element;
    }
});
...
elem.addClassName('disabledBtn');
elem.disable();
elem.update('Please Wait');
elem.redraw();
```

None of these items will work. The process will not update the UI until after the completion, and the user has redirected away. For reference, this is a pretty intensive form with a good few seconds of processing required during its submission, so this is a UX nightmare.

Has anybody else come across this situation?

Comment: Having same problem here... any update on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out.

As this is technically a workaround, rather than a solution to the problem, I'd still be open to other answers that may solve the issue outright.

I thought about this 'process' terminology, and how I could effectively end the process - thereby applying the styles, and start another one to submit the form.

The way I figured this out was to take the final stage of my code (the form submission) and push it into an asynchronous process. This way, the styling and validation 'process' will complete, with the style changes taking effect immediately, and the form submission will happen at some point after this.

I managed this asynchronous process with `setTimeout()`

```
elem.observe('click', function(e) {
    // [Disabled styles]
    // [Form Validity]
    if (!valid) {
        // [Reverse Button Disabling]
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){ $('myform').submit(); }, 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stopping the event first (in case your button is an actual `type="submit"`)? i.e.

```
elem.observe('click', function(e) {
    e.stop(); // prevent the default actions

    // [Disabled styles]
    // [Form Validity]

    if (!valid) {
        // [Reverse Button Disabling]
    } else {
        $('myform').submit();
    }
});
```